# Building a new system in Flex / Air a good idea?

Tags: apache-flex, enterprise

This maybe a bit of a 'wide' question, but am putting together a brief overview of a new system I'm proposing at work.

It will be a POS style system, that does quotes and invoices + crm for our work enviroment across 100 + locations.

It will communicate with server via the Internet. Flex / Air feature set (offline SQL is Internet goes down, Rich communications, rich client environment etc), the fact that we run Macs + PC makes it looks like a great choice. I know HTML 5 has offline SQL and stuff, but flex feature set is way more comprehensive / usable etc..

Something just feels risky about using Flex / Air, versus HTML.

Is anyone doing any big corporate Flex / Air projects that need to last a long time? Or are you pushing HTML and its new technologies to provide a more safe investment.

Comment: I'm working with a client that is one of the biggest publishers of Children's books in the world and they are using Flex to build some automation software as part of their eBook initiative.  If that isn't an investment they hope will last a long time, I'm not sure what is.  Nevertheless, I voted to close.  Questions like this are too open ended; you should be asking yourself "What best suits my business needs" regardless of what others are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have developed some fairly large systems in Flex for various types of businesses and IMO, this was the best technology choice we could make. The Flash Player and the Flex SDK certainly have their issues, especially if you push the boundaries in terms of performance, but in the end there is no valid alternative that offers you a ubiquitous runtime, with a single codebase, that is so widely used.

I think it's safe to say that the Flash platform and Flex/AIR have reached a certain level of maturity. There is tooling, frameworks, libraries, a vibrant community, ... Flash is everywhere and is not going anywhere soon.